# Parsing different class items of a page with Ruby and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I need to parse the images of this web page http://www.olx.com.br/loja/id/122315.

I'm trying to take the links of the img src using Nokogiri, because i'll save these links on the database of my application.

This code gets all the elements that I need (21), but i'm having trouble to get the output that i want...

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'


site = open ('http://www.olx.com.br/loja/id/122315')
site_lido = site.read
site_html = Nokogiri::HTML(site_lido)

site_html.at_css('#main-ad-list').css('.item').css('.col-1').css('.OLXad-list-image-box').count
```

If I use this code:

```
site_html.at_css('#main-ad-list').css('.item').css('.col-1').css('.OLXad-list-image-box').children.display
```

I get this Output:

```
<span class="no-photo">sem foto</span>

<img class="image" src="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/68/689721024565019.jpg" alt="CHEVROLET ONIX 1.0 MPFI LT 8V FLEX 4P MANUAL - 2016">

<span class="no-photo">sem foto</span>

<span class="no-photo">sem foto</span>

<span class="no-photo">sem foto</span>

<span class="no-photo">sem foto</span>

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/640717028616332.jpg" alt="RENAULT SANDERO 1.0 EXPRESSION 16V FLEX 4P MANUAL - 2017">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/649717026459313.jpg" alt="HYUNDAI HB20 1.0 COMFORT 12V FLEX 4P MANUAL - 2016">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/643717023799626.jpg" alt="FORD ECOSPORT 2.0 SE 16V FLEX 4P POWERSHIFT - 2015">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/641717028095520.jpg" alt="FIAT SIENA 1.0 MPI FIRE CELEBRATION 8V FLEX 4P MANUAL - 2010">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/647717020502693.jpg" alt="FIAT FIORINO 1.4 MPI FURG 8V FLEX 2P MANUAL - 2016">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/644717022311605.jpg" alt="FIAT FIORINO 1.4 MPI FURG 8V FLEX 2P MANUAL - 2016">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/642717021110547.jpg" alt="CHEVROLET ONIX 1.0 MPFI LT 8V FLEX 4P MANUAL - 2016">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/59/599711024752265.jpg" alt="HONDA CRV 2009/2010 2.0 LX 4X2 16V GASOLINA 4P AUTOMTICO - 2010">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/59/597711029493606.jpg" alt="TOYOTA COROLLA 2012/2013 2.0 XRS 16V FLEX 4P AUTOMTICO - 2013">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/57/577710022331072.jpg" alt="FIAT STRADA 1.4 MPI WORKING CS 8V FLEX 2P MANUAL - 2016">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/57/573710026456008.jpg" alt="CHEVROLET ONIX 1.0 MPFI LT 8V FLEX 4P MANUAL - 2016">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/10/109713018515279.jpg" alt="Farol Traseiro Em Led Com Carregamento Usb">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/23/235706014933596.jpg" alt="Hilux 2013 SRV Diesel 4x4 - 2013">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/23/233706015584450.jpg" alt="New Fiesta 2014 1.6 Automatico - 2014">

<img class="image lazy" src="//static.bn-static.com/img-46150/desktop/transparent.png" data-original="http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/23/239706014799171.jpg" alt="C3 2012 1.4 Completo - 2012">
```

But i need to get THIS output, and i need to put it on an array:

```
sem foto
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/68/689721024565019.jpg
sem foto
sem foto
sem foto
sem foto
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/640717028616332.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/649717026459313.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/643717023799626.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/641717028095520.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/647717020502693.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/644717022311605.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/64/642717021110547.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/59/599711024752265.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/59/597711029493606.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/57/577710022331072.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/57/573710026456008.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/10/109713018515279.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/23/235706014933596.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/23/233706015584450.jpg
http://img.olx.com.br/thumbsli/23/239706014799171.jpg
```

If i try to change the parse method to this:

```
site_html.at_css('#main-ad-list').css('.item').css('.OLXad-list-image-box').css('.image').each do |aaa|
    puts aaa.values
end
```

I can get closer to the desired output but i only get 16 items, not 21... i need the 21 items of the page. This is happening because when the item doesn't have an image, the class is "span" and not "image"...

How can I get the desired output?

**EDIT WITH THE SOLUTION (Mark Thomas solution):**

The desired output can be obtained with this code:

```
array = []

site_html.css('#main-ad-list .OLXad-list-image-box').xpath('span|img[@class="image"]/@src|img[@class="image lazy"]/@data-original').each do |q|  
        array.push q.text
end

puts array
```

Comment: Rather than loop over the nodeset pushing each onto an array, you can simply do this: `array = site_html.css('...').xpath('...').map(&:text)`

Comment: Cool. It's possible to simplify the code with this structure too ?

`categorias = []

site_html.css('#main-ad-list .OLXad-list-line-2').xpath('p[@class="text detail-category"]').each do |q|
    categorias.push q.children.first.text.gsub!(/[\t\n]/,"")
end`

I tried to use same simplification here but i got errors.

`teste = site_html.css('#main-ad-list .OLXad-list-line-2').xpath('p[@class="text detail-category"]').map(&:children.first.text.gsub!(/[\t\n]/,""))`

Comment: use `.map{|q| q.children.first.text.strip}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath supports logical OR logic like that. If you're not afraid of combining a CSS selector with an XPath statement:

```
site_html.css('#main-ad-list .OLXad-list-image-box').xpath('span|img/@data-original')
```

**Edit**: to get the `img` where there is no `@data original` attribute, I noticed there is a different class name, so we can add another option to the XPath, checking the class name of the `img` element:

```
site_html.css('#main-ad-list .OLXad-list-image-box').xpath('span|img[@class="image"]/@src|img[@class="image lazy"]/@data-original')
```

I'll break down the XPath part:

`span | img[@class="image"]/@src | img[@class="image lazy"]/@data-original`

which means include any of the following:

- `span`
- `img` with a class of `image`, its `src` attribute
- `img` with a class of `image lazy`, its `data-original` attribute

Comment: it almost worked. but for some reason this code returns only 20 elements instead of 21... in the 2nd item it doesn't have the "data-original", just the src. it's possible to correct that with xpath ?

Comment: i tried this:
`
site_html.at_css('#main-ad-list').css('.OLXad-list-image-box').xpath('span|img/@src|img/@data-original').each do |q|
    puts q.text
end
`

But it's taking the links of all the "src" itens too...

Comment: You know a way to solve this problem of the second element ?

Comment: It appears that the class is `image lazy` for 15 of them, which I guess is supposed to lazy-load the images, although none of them appeared in a web browser for me. The other is just class `image`. You can certainly add more conditional logic for that.

Comment: there's a way to put the conditional logic into the xpath ? something like ... if it's different from image-lazy, then search with img/src, otherwise not.

Comment: Also notice I combined your css method calls into one. My preference is not to chain them. Probably performs better too.

Comment: Wow... that was perfect man... thank you very much for all the help. I didn't know that i could use conditional expressions inside the xpath like that... i didn't know that i could chain the css also.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works

```
 array_of_items = []

 site_html.at_css('#main-ad-list').css('.item').css('.col-1').css('.OLXad-list-image-box').children.each do |child|

   array_of_items << (child.name == 'img' ? child.attr['data-original'] : child.text)

 end
```

Comment: the output of array_of_itens was that:  
  
text  
span  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
span  
text  
text  
span  
text  
text  
span  
text  
text  
span  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
text  
img  
text  
  
didn't work...

Comment: try wrapping the ternary expression in `( )`